# Grouping Images for Product colour variant not working - Shopify/Liquid

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to implement grouping of product image variants in my Shopify theme following this [tutorial](http://littlesnippets.ca/blogs/tutorials/15665261-grouping-images-with-variantshttp://).

I'm pretty sure I've done everything right up until I reach the Javascript element. I know that I have labelled my images correctly in the Shopify Admin. I've put the JS at the bottom of my product.liquid file and altered slightly to resemble my code however there is a part at the end of the tutorial referencing the JS snippet below which I don't understand or know where it needs to go. I'm presuming it needs to go in my script.js file but I'm not sure.

JS:

```
var switchImage = function(newImageSrc, newImage, mainImageDomEl) {
  jQuery(mainImageDomEl).attr('src', newImageSrc);
  $(mainImageDomEl).parents('a').attr('href', newImageSrc);
};
```

My code is as follows:

product.liquid:

```
  <!-- Begin product photos -->

  {% assign featured_image = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
  <!-- Begin featured image -->
  <div class="product-single__photos image featured" id="ProductPhoto">
    <a href="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" id="placeholder">
      <img src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" id="ProductPhotoImg" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- End product image -->

  {% comment %}
    Create thumbnails if we have more than one product image.
  {% endcomment %}

  {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
  <!-- Begin thumbnails -->
  <ul class="grid-uniform">
    <div class="thumbs clearfix">
    {% assign featured_alt = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1 %}
      {% for image in product.images %}
        {% if image.alt == featured_alt or image == featured_image %}
          {% unless forloop.first %}
              <li class="image grid_item">
                <a href="{{ image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" data-original-image="{{ image | product_img_url: '1024x1024' }}">
                  <img src="{{ image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" />
                </a>
              </li>
          {% endunless %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </ul>
  <!-- End thumbnails -->
  {% endif %}

<!-- End product photos -->
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var images = [];

{% for image in product.images %}
  images.push({url: "{{ image | product_img_url: '1024x1024' }}", alt:     "{{ image.alt }}"});
{% endfor %}

var thumbnails = $(".thumbs");                         
$('#product-select-option-0').change(function() {
var selected = $(this).val(), mainImage = jQuery('.featured img').attr('src');
thumbnails.hide().html("");
arr = [];

var addImage = $.each( images, function( i, image ) {
  var alt = images[i].alt, url = images[i].url;   
  if (alt == selected || url == mainImage) {
    thumbnails.append('<li class="grid_item"><a href="' + url + '" data-original-image="' + url + '"><img src="' + url + '" alt="' + alt + '"></a></li>');
  }
 });
 arr.push(addImage);
 $.when.apply($, arr).done(function () {
   thumbnails.fadeIn(); 
   $('#product .thumbs a').on('click', function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
   switchImageTwo($(this).attr('href'), null, $('.featured img')[0]);
   });
  });
 });
});
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Towards the end of your js you are calling a function called `switchImageTwo`, which you haven't defined anywhere yet. The js snippet you are unsure about is an example of what the `switchImage` function could look like (or `switchImageTwo` in your case). You can put this function with your existing js, above the line `$.when.apply...` should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for explaining that for me, I tried what you suggested but that hasn't seemed to have made any difference. I don't know if I'm missing a class somewhere but the thumbnail images just aren't changing. If you have any other suggestions I would love to hear them, been stuck on this for ages. Many thanks!